# How to deal with more than one SD card slot

Tags: android, android-sdcard

In my app, I store the user's app data using MySQLite databases, and I allow the user to backup the app data to the SD card within a folder that I create on the SD card (let's call it MyAppFolder). On Android devices that have only a single SD card slot, everything works fine (e.g. my Droid).

However, on devices such as the Galaxy S that have more than 1 SD card, things don't work. Unfortunately, I don't actually have one of these devices, so I can't debug anything, I can only go by user reports. I also did some searching and found this is a known issue. However, I did not find any solutions that didn't involve just hardcoding the other paths that get used,  so I'm looking for some help with that.

In my app, I check and see if MyAppFolder already exists. If not, I create that folder. The folder is always created successfully, although it is created on the "internal" memory slot returned by getExternalStorageDirectory() when there are 2 slots present. However, the files do not get created and copied there. I don't understand why the folder is created, but the files are not created.

Can someone tell me how I can modify this code to work for devices with 2 card slots as well as 1 card slot? I'd prefer not to hard-code locations to check, but if that's the only way, I'll do it just to get things working.

Here is the code I use(slightly modified to make more readable here):

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
{
    File dataDirectory = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    if (root.canWrite())
    {
        String savePath = root + "/MyAppFolder/";
        File directory = new File(savePath);
        if( !directory.exists() )
        {
            directory.mkdirs();  //folder created successfully
        }

        String currentDBPath = "\\data\\my_app\\databases\\database.db";

        File currentDB = new File(datDirectory, currentDBPath);
        File backupDB = new File(savePath, "database.db");

        if (currentDB.exists()) 
        {
            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB[i]).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB[i]).getChannel();

            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());

            src.close();
            dst.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone tell me how I can modify this code to work for devices with 2 card slots as well as 1 card slot?

"External storage" does not mean "removable storage". "External storage" means "mountable storage" -- IOW, the user has access to that storage when they plug their device into a host machine via a USB cable.

Android, at present, is designed to allow developers to write things to *one* external storage point, and it is up to the device manufacturer whether that is fixed flash or something removable. Hence, you should be backing things up to external storage, not thinking that you are backing things up to an SD card.

> Can someone tell me how I can modify this code to work for devices with 2 card slots as well as 1 card slot?

Use [`getDatabasePath()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29) to get a database path, rather than the gyrations you are presently going through. Never use concatenation to create paths, the way you are with `root + "/MyAppFolder/"` -- use a `File` constructor, as you are elsewhere. Make sure you hold the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. Beyond that, this should work fine for any device with sufficient external storage to hold your database, regardless of how many "card slots" the device may have.

Comment: thanks. Question though: Are you suggesting that, if I create the directory as File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyAppFolder"); and  use getDatabasePath() instead of the internal DB path, this will make things work for the Galaxy S (& similar devices)? I understand that's a cleaner way to code it, but ultimately, what exactly does that change which will allow the files to write successfully, which isn't currently being done? I have the permission set, and this works fine on my Droid and emulators. I get the code change. But what behavior is being changed?

Comment: @Michael: I am not aware of any problems in writing to external storage on "the Galaxy S (& similar devices)". If nobody could write to external storage on those devices, I'd've heard about it. Heck, *you'd* have heard about it, since a bug like that would have been covered by major media outlets. I'm merely pointing out a few oddities in what I see from what you have posted, in hopes that perhaps it will help you track down whatever issue lies with your code and how it accesses external storage.

Comment: Thanks again. The user who pointed this out to me hooked his device up to a computer. He said that he could see both drives, and could see the MyAppFolder sitting there. But there were no files inside the folder. So then, I'm not crazy in believing that, if the folder can be created successfully, then the files should be able to be created as well? Have you encountered any common culprits that could cause a failure when trying to create a file in the area returned by getExternalStorageDirectory()? I don't understand why the code can work on a Droid, but not a Galaxy S, that's all

Comment: @Michael: "So then, I'm not crazy in believing that, if the folder can be created successfully, then the files should be able to be created as well?" -- yes, you are not crazy. At least not with respect to this. :-) "Have you encountered any common culprits that could cause a failure when trying to create a file in the area returned by getExternalStorageDirectory()?" -- none that fit your symptoms. It's easy to forget `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, for example, but you couldn't create the directory. But `currentDBPath` is probably wrong on a Samsung as you have it coded, now that I think about it.

Comment: ok, I was under the impression that the DB location created by an app basically followed the same hierarchy. I'll re-work the code to make use of the function call. From what I've read, we have no way to create an emulator to accurately simulate a device such as the Galaxy S. Any parting thoughts on how I can possibly test this out in any way, outside of purchasing one of those devices?

Comment: @Michael: "I was under the impression that the DB location created by an app basically followed the same hierarchy." -- I seem to recall hearing that their root is different. In particular, the copy failing for one reason or another would explain your symptoms. "Any parting thoughts on how I can possibly test this out in any way, outside of purchasing one of those devices?" -- you can use a service like DeviceAnywhere, or find a friend with a Galaxy S, or try finding someone at your local Meetup/GTUG/other form of Android user group.